# How to make embedded segue respond to user action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue, uicontainerview

My PenViewController has three labels and a Container View, which means I am using an embedded segue. The thing about embedded segue, at least per my understanding, is that they are not caused by user actions the way push segues are. But now I need my Container View to show a different child respectively when a different label is clicked. How do I pass that data to the Container View? Here is my embed segue.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"embedded_segue_to_container_vc"]) {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[BCDPenDetailContainerViewController class]]) {
            BCDPenDetailContainerViewController *container = (BCDPenDetailContainerViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            container.details=self.details;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the `sender` to know which label got clicked?

Comment: You can use a `UITabBarController` as the embedded controller, hide the tab bar and set the tab controller's `selectedIndex` according to the label tapped

Comment: @spassas I don't understand the comment. The PenViewController three labels and a ContainerView below the labels. Also the labels are not in the Navigation Controller: they are in the proper body of PenViewController. That's the look and it's set in stone. My tabBar and my navBar are already busy.  So really, somehow, I need the embed segue to respond the the clicks of the labels.

Comment: By "responding" I suppose you mean that you want to change the embedded controller according to which label was tapped. Is that so, or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @reecon what sender? it's an embed segue. Even if I were to try to segue from a label to the container, the storyboard would not present me a segue option. So is there a different way to somehow tell the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method that one of the labels is the sender? I mean, strictly speaking, the `Container View` is the sender as far as the storyboard cares and it allows no other additional segue to the Container's accompanying ViewController.

Comment: Your contains view is just a UIView, so you can make an IBOutlet to it, if you need to add a new child view controller to it.

Comment: @spassas basically I need the **content** of my `Container View` to change based on which button is clicked. The Container View is to swap among its children based on which label is clicked. My design is `ParentOfContainerviewAndLabelsVC ->VCThatContainerviewSeguesTo -> [ChildOneVC || ChildTwoVC]`, such that VCThatContainerviewSeguesTo will swap ChildOneVC or ChildTwoVC as its content.

Comment: Ok, so make your `VCThatContainerviewSeguesTo` to be of class `UITabBarController`, set its `viewControllers` to be `ChildOneVC`, `ChildTwoVC` etc and then set its `selectedIndex` property according to the label tapped.

Comment: @rdelmar when I do that the child VC does not adhere to the bounds of the containerView IBOutlet

Comment: When you do what? How are you setting up the replacement child view controller?

Comment: @spassas that sounds like a potential solution except I don't see storyboard allowing me to drop IBActions from the labels into VCThatContainerviewSeguesTo since they do not belong to the same type: i.e. the labels and the container are siblings; whereas the VCThatContainerviewSeguesTo is effectively a nephew to the labels. So is there some other way to get the labels to talk to VCThatContainerviewSeguesTo in your scenario? Again the labels belong to ParentOfContainerviewAndLabelsVC

Comment: Yes. Create a property for your `VCThatContainerviewSeguesTo` (i.e `vCThatContainerviewSeguesTo`) in your `ParentOfContainerviewAndLabelsVC` and in `prepareForSegue` do `self.vCThatContainerviewSeguesTo = (VCThatContainerviewSeguesTo*)segue.destinationViewController`. So you can always access your container VC from your parent VC

Comment: @rdelmar when I treat the `Container View` as a mere UIView as in `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView` and then pass ChildTwoVC to it as `- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
    [self addChildViewController:content];
    content.view.frame = [self frameForContainedContentController];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}` which is basically what the docs say to do.

Comment: You should add the child view controller's view to the container view, not self.view.

Comment: @rdelmar thanks!!! your idea works. I replace view with containerView and that did it. Thank you!!!

Comment: @rdelmar will you please post as Response so other people looking for help may see this thread as solved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container view is just a UIView (with some IB magic thrown in), so you can create an IBOutlet to it if you need to reference it to change (or add) a child view controller. To add another child view controller, use the standard custom container controller api, and add the new controller's view to the container view,

```
-(IBAction)addNew:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *newVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewVC"];
    [self addChildViewController:newVC];
    [newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    newVC.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds; // containerView is the IBOutlet to the container view in the storyboard
    [self.containerView addSubview:newVC.view];
}
```